# Entity Framework 4.1 and T4 class generation. Is this design overkill?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, t4

I am trying to get some design validation on modeling a domain using EF4.1 and T4.

At design time I run a customized a T4 poco generator template that reads edmx and creates 3 partial classes:

1) domain-level class (where any specific business methods will reside). this is only generated one time. Once Gen'd it's owned.

2) poco class just properties and virtual navigation properties to related objects, loaded lazily. this can be regen'ed if/when any underlying columns in the database change.

3) metadata class with an internal class whose properties are decorated with data annotations to provide additional column-level validation before inserting / updating data.

Is this overkill? I liked the separation, namely between the poco and domain object so that I can add methods to the partial domain object at any time without having to worry about method loss when needing to rerun the T4 template after underlying data specs may change. What about the metadata class? Is that unnecessary if my application will be performing field validation?

Comment: I would say not so much "overkill" as "violation of SRP."

Comment: T4 template should not generate files which are supposed to be edited by developer. That is unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Craig - the objects don't really have any responsibilities other than to provide an object model of persistent data and expose some public methods that might provide business-related calculations. the changes these objects may experience are: 1) more column or navigation properties, which can be re-gened by the t4 template. 2) adding or changing of domain business methods. Do you suggest those business methods really belong in a service layer instead of the domain layer?

Comment: @Ladisav - The T4 template would gen a "start" file, if you will...and never regenerate it (this is the domain class). It will only regen the poco and metadata classes if underlying infrastructure changes. Conceptually, I figured this was acceptable...doesn't VS use T4 to generate start templates for MVC, for example?

Comment: @aaroncope Yes, putting business methods in a service layer rather than a domain layer is *exactly* what I think you should do. Similarly, validation is a UI concern, not a domain or service concern.

Comment: @CraigStuntz Thanks! Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @CraigStuntz - one last question. If I am using a services layer rather than domain layer, what are good practices for creating descriptive methods that would perform operations for **related** poco objects? (Especially for an object hierarchy)

Comment: To me, operations on related POCO objects *is* a service layer. Maybe this article helps? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AtTheBoundariesApplicationsAreNotObjectOriented.aspx

Comment: @CraigStuntz - yes that was helpful. it appears that by using POCO and Service Layers, i'm actually introducing a conceptual [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) and the POCOs really are nothing more than DTOs to/from the service layer...they aren't really "domain" objects, right? I considered a translation layer, but honestly I'm trying to get away from so much system/code maintenance, which is why I chose T4 generated POCOs in the first place. I'm really struggling with the best way to model this.

Comment: I actually disagree with Fowler that "anemic domain" is an anti-pattern, because I am *decidedly not* an OO purist. At any rate, I think Seeman nails it that mapped entities aren't even objects; they're the application boundary. At a minimum, you need (1) entities, to transfer to/from DB and (2) services, for business code and (3) tests. Start with that and add layers when needed. I use the above + repositories to abstract away the ObjectContext for testing.

Comment: @CraigStuntz - understood. to play devil's advocate, when you have a large quantity of objects that would relate to one other, couldn't a service layer very thick, clunky and out-of-hand very quickly? Sorry, i would move this to a chat, but i don't have enough points yet. :) Thanks for continuing the discussion with me.

Comment: Well, a service layer *is* your business logic. If that's "out of hand," then rethink your business. :)